# Difference in behaviour between time and /usr/bin/time in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash

I am teaching myself bash scripting and trying to create a script that completes the exercise...

*Write a script that stores the time it takes a command (your choice of command) to run in three variables, real, user, and system, corresponding to the three default times that time prints.*

I have been playing around with something like

```
output=$( /usr/bin/time -f "%E\n" ( eval "$@" 2>/dev/null 1>&2) 2>&1 )
```

The plan is to use the format flag to get an output string in some arbitrary format that I can then split into separate variables. For extra cred I am also trying to suppress the output of the original command using a subshell and output redirection.

This of course does not work. Trying to run a script containing just this line and the input "ls -l" and I get an error

```
command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

After some playing around I have noticed that...

```
time (ls -l)
```

Works fine but

```
/usr/bin/time (ls -l)
```

Gives the error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ls'
```

**Why the difference in behaviour between the built-in and the binary?**

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the `time` command, unlike `/usr/bin/time`, is built into the shell, so it can do things that an external command cannot.

The shell sees

```
/usr/bin/time (ls -l)
```

as a command `/usr/bin/time` with arguments.  Unescaped parentheses are not allowed in command arguments.  You'll get the same error if you type, for example:

```
/bin/echo (ls -l)
```

or even, using the builtin command:

```
echo (ls -l)
```

The builtin `time`, on the other hand, is designed to be more flexible. In fact the builtin `time` is a keyword, not a command; it's part of the syntax of the shell.

Quoting the bash documentation:

> The use of `time` as a reserved word permits the timing of shell
>   builtins, shell functions, and pipelines.  An external `time` command
>   cannot time these easily.